# angular combobox with ui-select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for a way to create a combobox (text input and dropdown select in one). The textbox should be linked to a model value as if it was a normal text input, but at the same time it should be possible to select a value from the dropdown which will be set as the text.

I've tried angular-ui-select (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) but was not able to get the required functionality. It's either only textfield or only allows to select from the dropdown. My user should be able to enter a custom text OR select from the dropdown.

I've tried with the code below which of course doesn't work, as my model element.customType is only set once a value from the dropdown is selected. Anyone aware of how this could be achieved with ui-select or maybe another directive?

```
<ui-select ng-model="element.customType" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter customType...">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="type in CUSTOM_TYPES">
     <div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(type)"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had also very similar problem before few months with that.

Jimmy, please take look on following documentations http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ and 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

Why don't you use proven`select` tag?

For combining select2 library and Angular js, you have to include css and js libraries as here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2#usage

**Note that you must include 2 DIFFERENT SELECT2 libraries: *PLAIN* select2 library AND select2 library from *ANGULAR-UI-SELECT2***

If you have the correct configuration, controller and service for getting your data, the HTML part is very simple, for an example:

> ```
> <select ui-select2 ng-model="selectedSingle" data-placeholder="-- Select One --">
>     <option></option>
>     <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
>  </select>
> ```

More details on https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2#working-with-dynamic-options

I also used the same references, hope you will solve it very quickly :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not entirely sure as how this would help in my case. Seems to be a similiar solution thatn ui-select with the downside that it's deprecated and they point to the ui-select project instead. I've just implemented a typeahead solution for now from angular bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap).

Comment: My opinion is that this typehead solution is not powerful enough. The reason why I gave you this suggestion is that with the mentioned select2 libraries you can have single- and multiple selection, with search of course. Have look on this example: http://www.bootply.com/vHj8Tv7uJu . Is that what you need?

Comment: I agree, the typeahead is of course not optimal but will suffice for now. I was rather looking for a way to merge a text input AND a select input in one. At least in my book that's what the definition of a combobox is. All the solutions I found only allow you to use the textfield as a search to select (single/multiple) items from the select input but won't allow you to also have a user enter custom text.

Comment: Honestly @jimmy, I'm wondering that example in my previous comment (especially the 'Tag Picker') can't help you. You can always play with css, because if I understand you correctly, the Tag Picker is the combination that you are searching for. I really don't have more ideas to help you :D